# php multiple select option from database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following and would like to be able to multiple select and insert in the database.

```
<select name="accred">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<?
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM stock_livestock_accred ORDER BY name ASC" );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $row->id ?>"<?= $this->row->accred == $row->id ? " selected" : "" ?>><?= $row->name ?></option>
<?  } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Use <select name="accred[]" multiple> in HTML

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Can you clarify "would like to be able to multiple select...". What is the problem, what have your tried, what unexpected results do your get? Please see [ask].

Comment: yes tried, but not saving the selection, thanks

Answer (score 0):

first change your `HTML` like this

```
<select name="accred[]" multiple>

        <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
        <?
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock_livestock_accred ORDER BY name ASC");
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $row->id ?>"<?= $this->row->accred == $row->id ? " selected" : "" ?>><?= $row->name ?></option>
        <?  } ?>
        </select>
```

and then get the value of `select` element like below

```
<?php $accred=$_POST['accred'];?>
```

and you can do whatever you want this with your database

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select name="accred" multiple>
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<?
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM stock_livestock_accred ORDER BY name ASC" );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $row->id ?>"<?= $this->row->accred == $row->id ? " selected" : "" ?>><?= $row->name ?></option>
<?  } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the example:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="accred[]" multiple> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```